# Why do I get this message (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) while running my test code?

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, junit5

I am using maven while building my java project, and I am using JUnit5 framework to test, when I tried to running the test code, I got this message:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-cli) on project transaction-processor: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

this is the POM.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.progressoft.induction</groupId>
    <artifactId>transaction-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                   
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

How can I solve this, and what is the problem?

Comment: It looks like surefire is expecting you to have atleast one test case. Either write a unit test case in properly defined structure or set -DfailIfNoTests=false

Comment: What is your mvn command to run ?

Answer (score 0):

I added the following plugin info in POM file that solved the problem.

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>                    
            </plugin>
```